# A web service for checking broken links

Tags: webapp-rec

Please recommend a web service that checks for broken links on a web site.

Not required, but would be nice to have:

- checks standards-compliance of the HTML, CSS, Javascript, ...
- displays permanent redirects

Comment: What does the title have in common with your actual question?

Comment: @ivo I updated for clarity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

w3.org provides great resources for link validation .
http://validator.w3.org/checklink/